# Cant get MethodInvoker to return a bool

Tags: c#, multithreading

Im in need of accessing a shared logfile from within my threads, so i now try to use the MethodInvoker to read the file and return a bool depending on if it has found an entry.. But getting this error, cannot figure out how to get it to return me a bool:

> Cannot convert anonymous method to delegate type
>   'System.Windows.Forms.MethodInvoker' because some of the return types
>   in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return
>   type

```
    private void searchLogInThread(string msg, string fileName)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(
                       delegate
                       {
                           StreamReader re = File.OpenText(fileName);

                           string input = null;
                           while ((input = re.ReadLine()) != null)
                           {

                               if (input.Contains(msg))
                               {
                                   re.Close();
                                   return true;
                               }

                           }
                           re.Close();
                           return false;
                       }
                       ));
    }
```

Comment: *because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type* The delegate return type is `void` but you're trying to return a `bool`. It's all over the compiler error message!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Description

The MethodInvoker is a delegate with no result. You need to create your own.

#### Sample

```
public delegate bool MethodInvokerWithBooleanResult();

Invoke(new MethodInvokerWithBooleanResult(
             delegate
             {
                            // do something and return a bool
                            return true;
             }
         ));
```

### Update

Another way is to use `Func<bool>`

```
Invoke(new Func<bool>(
        delegate
        {
                    // do something and return a bool
                    return true;
        }
    ));
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171(v=vs.140).aspx)

Comment: Why would you declare your own delegate when `Func<bool>` achieves the same goal?

Comment: @user1213488: No, you haven't. I mean not unless you have made other changes. Otherwise all of your code would be running on the UI thread. You were still wanting to read the file on a background thread right?

Answer (score 4):

[`MethodInvoker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.methodinvoker.aspx) can't return anything. The delegate has a `void` return type. If you need a value to be returned, you need to use a different delegate (e.g. `Func<bool>`).

Assuming this is within a control, I think you're going about it all in the wrong way anyway - you're using `Control.Invoke`, which will execute all of that code (reading files) *in the UI thread*. Don't do that.

Also, there's no indication of how you'd be using the result anyway... basically, I think you need to rethink your design significantly. It's confused at the moment.

Comment: Ahhh, could you write a short example of it? Would be greatly appreciated :))

Comment: @user1213488: Not really - there's enough wrong with your code that we can't really tell what you're trying to achieve. (And I'm about to be walking for about half an hour...)

Answer (score 0):

`MethodInvoker` does not define a return type. There are various different ways to get a return value back from an anonymous method or lambda expression. But, it appears like you may have a fundamental misunderstanding of how `Invoke` is suppose to be used. The code you provided will not run on a background thread at all.

I would use the `Task` class to read the file in the background. Use `StartNew` to get a `Func<TResult>` delegate running on a background thread. Then you can call `ContinueWith` to transfer control back to the UI where you can extract the return value and manipulate any controls with it.

```
private void searchLogInThread(string msg, string fileName)
{
  Task.Factory
    .StartNew(() =>
    {
      // This executes on a background thread.

      using (StreamReader re = File.OpenText(fileName))
      {
        string input = null;
        while ((input = re.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
          if (input.Contains(msg))
          {
            return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }
    })
    .ContinueWith(task =>
    {
      // This executes on the UI thread.

      bool result = task.Result; // Extract result from the task here.

      MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());

    }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext);
}
```